# Does the construction "should + of + past participle" exist?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, construction

There was someone on Facebook who commented like this:

> Next time she should of flushed the toilet.

At first, I thought he had misspelled "should have", then I was thinking that it's not correct to use **should have** (right?)  in the future construction (I suspect 'next time' he meant to say about future). I also checked the Ngram viewer about the usage of **should of** and **should + of + past participle** (I randomly chose *known*).

These are the results, by the way:

The usage of **[should of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20of%3B%2Cc0)**

[image]

The usage of **[should of known](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should%20of%20known&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20of%20known%3B%2Cc0)**

[image]

Now, my question is, does that construction exist? (I've never seen it before) If that's just a misspelling, then why is the construction used in many books (According to Ngram viewer)? What construction is it called then?

Comment: You ran the wrong Ngrams test. Try [this comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+have+known%2Cshould+of+known&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20known%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20of%20known%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on bad English, so no useful answer can come from it

Comment: @gotube Why does no userful answer come from it? It's a mistake that many native speakers make when writing, so it is likely to be useful to other learners who don't know which is correct.

Comment: The sentence you found is something i really really often encountered. It happenes when a german translates a sentence to english without actually translating it, meaning the sentence is just literally translated with no effords to match english grammar forms. "I had of known" is another example when a german tries to translate "I have known about this", and the all-time misused "If you will" > It might sound elegant to a native speaker cause it's basiscally correct, but the german wanted to say "If you want", because "will" is the word for wanting.

Comment: @clockw0rk Sorry, but that's just bollocks. The idiom "if you will" certainly does not come from German speakers incorrectly translating to English, rather the English auxiliary "will" and the German verb ultimately come from the same root, and it still has retained some of its old meaning.

Also, I cannot think of a way a German could (literally) translate "Ich habe das gewusst / I have known about this" to "I had of known". Word for word, it's more like "I have that known".

Comment: The pair of words "Should of" is perfectly valid in constructions like "You should of course remember that <something is true.>". Your first ngram will be counting examples like that.

Comment: @alephzero the vast majority appear to be OCR splicing columnar text together, e.g. "it was thereupon ordered that he should | on this day attend the Court" with "an order | of the 12th of Jan. last..." becoming "that he should of the 12th of Jan". Can't seem to link the extensive URL here without it being mangled.

Comment: von == of , so "ich wusste davon" = i had of known . but i agree that this is not helpfull here

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why does that construction exist?

Because in *spoken* language, *should **have*** and *should **of*** are indistinguishable (when enunciated as contracted ***should've***). And some native speakers are so ignorant they don't understand that basic syntax requires an auxiliary verb after ***should***, not a preposition.

But note that some perfectly competent Anglophones may *deliberately* write the incorrect version sometimes as a facetious usage. OP's cited Facebook poster probably *isn't* very competent, given that "next time" is *future*, so the auxiliary ***have*** (part of a "Present Perfect = Past" verb form) shouldn't be there anyway. But even people who know perfectly well that it's "incorrect" sometimes write things like ***a whole 'nother ballgame*** for much the same reason.

---

I don't know why OP wrote *it's not correct to use **should have***. That's *exactly* what the Facebook writer should of<sup>1</sup> written!

---

<sup>1</sup> In case it's not obvious, that's me being facetious! But actually whereas one ***should've = should have** done something **in the past***, when talking about a future "next time" it's what one ***should do*** (infinitive ***do***, not ***have*** + Past Participle ***done***).

Comment: "some native speakers are so ignorant they don't understand that basic syntax requires an auxiliary verb after should, not a preposition." - this. Also you see could of, would of, might of, etc. I recently saw 'ought to of' in a colleague's email, and he was not junior or young.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible for people who *do* know better to make this mistake through lack of attention. I know that I'm quite capable of writing ***it's*** and ***there*** instead of ***its*** and ***their***, for example, even though I certainly ***know*** correct usage on that front. I find it hard to imagine myself using ***of*** unwittingly like this (but over the years I'll often have written it "facetiously"). At the end of the day though, if I was pretty certain such an email writer *wasn't* "joking", I'd take it as a strong indicator of general incompetence).

Comment: "if I was pretty certain ... I'd take it as a strong indicator of general incompetence". About right.

Comment: "Because in *spoken* language, *should **have*** and *should **of*** are indistinguishable" That's somewhat exaggerated. "You should have more meat loaf." is pronounced quite differently from "You should of more meat loaf." It varies with the context.

Comment: I think it's actually the contraction "should've" that's indistinguishable, which is almost universally used when it's used as an auxiliary verb phrase. It doesn't apply when "have" is the main verb itself. @MichaelHardy

Comment: *"I don't know why OP wrote it's not correct to use should have."* As they wrote in their question, user516076 thinks it's not correct because "next time" refers to the future but "should have" refers to the past. After "should of" is corrected to "should have", I agree with user516076 that the quote "Next time she should have flushed the toilet" sounds odd to me. I would instead say either "Next time she should flush the toilet" (future) or "She should have flushed the toilet" (past).

Comment: @Bavi_H: Agreed. I confess I didn't read the original question to that level of detail. But it would have been hard for me to forgo the chance to write *...exactly what [he] **should of** written!*

Comment: (But I'll edit out the possibility of the Facebook poster being *deliberately* facetious, given that fairly clear evidence of suspect linguistic competence! :)

Comment: "some native speakers are so ignorant they don't understand that basic syntax requires an auxiliary verb after should, not a preposition" This is seems a bit insulting, but I guess it is quite literally true. I would guess that most native speakers can't correctly identify what prepositions or auxiliary verbs are.

Comment: Most native speakers don't give two hoots about rules of syntax, auxiliary verbs, etc, all of which are concepts created by linguists to describe what people actually say. I'm not saying "should of" should be considered "correct" rather than "a common mistake", but the level of snooty condescension in this answer is well over the top.

Comment: @IMSoP: That's  ridiculously extreme perspective on *your* part. I'm not formally "a linguist", but I'm sure all those who *do* justifiably merit that label would agree that "valid syntax" is something all native speakers of all languages are very cognisant of. Not necessarily *consciously*, but all native speakers recognise "incorrect phrasing" even if they've no idea what "syntax" means (and even though not all native speakers *agree* with others as regards valid or invalid constructions. A sloppy native speaker might say he would of done something, but only nns would say he would of did it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Again, my objection was not to calling it incorrect, but using condescending language like "so ignorant" and "perfectly competent", which serve no purpose other than to make you feel superior.

Comment: The intention was to make my *readers* feel superior. Even though the target audience here are non-native speakers, I'm sure almost all would either *already* know the relevant syntax, or would understand it as soon as the contracted ***have / of*** homophony is explicitly pointed out. But if you don't like that aspect of my style, there's not much I can or will do about it.

Comment: "Next time, she should have..." is perfectly fine, it's just obscure. E.g: "She explained that the previous bathroom visitor had committed terrible acts upon the toilet. However, following her visit, the bathroom was also stinky. Next time, she should be sure to have flushed the toilet before complaining."

Comment: @fectin I don't agree that your examples are in the same tense. However, I think it can be made to work: "The first time, she flushed. The next time, she should have flushed." It works because everything is still past tense.

Comment: @JounceCracklePop Yeah, mine had some slight of hand. Yours is better.

Comment: "And some native speakers are so ignorant"  -1 from me for this sentence.  There's no reason to insult people.  Language drifts due to things like this all the time; ignorance is unrelated.  And this will come across as an insult to readers - and probably especially by some in minorities commonly called ignorant.

Comment: @Joe: Lord save me from virtue signallers! This site is *aimed* at non-native speakers, I'm just taking a good-natured pop at my fellow native Anglophones - primarily to remind my target audience that they shouldn't feel too despondent if they find some aspects of English confusing, since even we natives sometimes make mistakes. Hopefully that reminder is being given in a context where the average reader can *already* see the nature of the "error" here by the time he reads my "sideswipe", so he can get to feel *just a little* smug.

Answer (score 12):

"Should of" is a misspelling of "should've"; "should've" is pronounced the same as (or very close to) "should of". It is indeed incorrect to use "should've" for future event. It should be just "Next time, she should flush the toilet."

Comment: Maybe this is not about future events. Contrast "Next time, she should flush the toilets." and "The next time she should have flushed the toilets, she discovered that there was no water in the tank."

Comment: @Stef The context is given in the question, and doesn't match that interpretation.

Comment: @IMSoP The only context I see in the question is "There was someone on Facebook who commented". I don't see how you jump from that meagre piece of information to "it was not in the past".

Comment: @Stef The quote is given as a complete sentence. There's no way to fit your convoluted conditional clause around the quote.

Comment: The quote given makes no sense for two reasons, it uses "should of", and it refers to a future event in the past tense.  Salvaging useful meaning from it is difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Using "should of" when "should have" would be correct standard English grammar is a common usage. In some cases this occurs from hearing "should've" (intended as short for "should have") as "should of" because there is little if any difference in sound.  But I think (although I cannot prove) that this use of "should of"  is also a common, and so arguably "correct", use in certain English dialects.

Examples:

> - I should have known better.[image: Green Check]
> - I should of known better.[image: Red X]

Using "should have" for a future event, instead of just "should" is also incorrect, but is also not uncommon among fluent speakers. I suspect it comes from mentally placing oneself after the future event has occurred, and then looking back on it. Or it may just be that correction of a past event is so much more common that the "should have" form leaps to the mind, even when it is not correct. This is supported by the use of a past tense form of "flush" in the example.

In any case, the fully correct version dealing with an anticipated future event would be:

> Next time, she should flush the toilet.

In this form the issue of "of" vs "have" goes away, because neither is needed or wanted.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one way "should + of" phrasing can be used:

*He should, of course, have used correct grammar on his college application.*

Comment: -1 too absolutist, and ignoring dialect.